# JS click event on second element with similar behavior doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble getting some notification type elements to show and hide accordingly. what i want to acomplish is have two or more popup elements show on page start. then when clicking one element's ".alert-close" block, it shrinks and hides the content, leaving just the ".alert-open" block visible. then on clicking this block, it sizes back up and shows the content. so far so good, this works. same for the second element. closing and showing it works. not for the tricky part. When one of the elements is closed (minimized), i can't register the click on the second element (to minimize this one also). What am I missing? i tried e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() at the end of each query, didn't help. I need to be able to register the click on any number of similar events.

However, there is also the .alert-kill block, this one can be clicked and works on a the second element when the first one is mimized.

Second question, how could i automate this without needing to write the same js for two or more similar elements, only different by id? (the code below is my test code, obviously writing js for each element by id is not correct, but since they have the same classes i cannot use these classes alone to detect the click event as it applies the changes to all elements, i just used two ids now to test the functionality with two elements)

EDIT: removed ids and used just classes. the code now looks like this:

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="alert-container">
    <div id="alert-offer" class="alert-popup"> 
        <a class="alert-kill" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>          
        <div class="pull-left close-alert">         
            <a class="alert-close" href="#" title="click to shrink"><div class="alert-icon" style="background-image:url('new/images/alert-offer.png');"></div></a> 
            <a class="alert-open hide" href="#" title="click to expand"><div class="alert-icon" style="background-image:url('new/images/alert-offer.png');"></div></a>       
        </div>     
        <div class="row top-10 content-row">
           CONTENT 1
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div id="alert-event" class="alert-popup"> 
        <a class="alert-kill" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>          
        <div class="pull-left close-alert">         
            <a class="alert-close" href="#" title="click to shrink"><div class="alert-icon" style="background-image:url('new/images/avatar.jpg');"></div></a> 
            <a class="alert-open hide" href="#" title="click to expand"><div class="alert-icon" style="background-image:url('new/images/avatar.jpg');"></div></a>       
        </div>     
        <div class="row top-10 content-row">
            CONTENT 2
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>


<script>
var state = "open" ;
$(".alert-container").on("click", ".alert-popup .alert-close", function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (state !== "open")
        return;

    var $container = $(".alert-popup");            
    var $content = $(".alert-popup .content-row");

    $container.css({
        "right": "-270px",
        "height": "40px",
        "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
    });
    $content.css({
        "transform":"scale(.5)",
        "transform-origin":"0 0",
        "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
    });

    state = "close";
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass("hide");            
    $(".alert-popup .alert-open").removeClass("hide");
});

$(".alert-container").on("click", ".alert-popup .alert-open", function(e){    
    var state = "close";
    e.preventDefault();
    if (state === "open")
        return;
    var $container = $(".alert-popup");
    var $content = $(".alert-popup .content-row");
    $container.css({
        "right": "0px",
        "height": "80px",
        "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
    });
    $content.css({
        "transform":"scale(1)",
        "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
    });
    state = "open";
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass("hide");
    $(".alert-popup .alert-close").removeClass("hide");
});

$(".alert-container").on("click", ".alert-popup .alert-kill", function(e){            
    $(".alert-popup").css("display","none");            
});
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you've only a single `state` for all the pop-ups. You need to store a separate "state" for each pop-up instead.

Comment: Use class to add events and then use $(this) to get current clicked element and based on that do your further opertaions

Comment: $(this) instead of what @R.K.Saini? i tried $(this) instead of $("body"), obviously it wasn't correct

Comment: still haven't figured it out. anyone?

Comment: @Teemu, how can i detect the state for individual elements, yet without using IDs to target them?

Comment: Please create an MCVE for your issue: I have tried placing your code in a snippet, but nothing shows up.

Comment: @Terry , not sure what else to do to make it more verifiable as the code above is identical to that which i am using to test locally. for some reason i cannot close the ".alert-container" div here in this markdown. maybe that's why it wasn't working in your snippet?

Comment: Create an example that works: visually the way it should be presented. Right now the classes are arbitrary, and you should specify what library needs to be loaded. If you convert your code into a code snippet, you will see that it does not work at all.

Comment: @Terry , hope it helps. edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".alert-container").on("click", ".alert-popup .alert-close", function(e){           
        var state = "open" ;
        e.preventDefault();
        if (state !== "open")
            return;

        var $container = $(e.target).closest(".alert-popup");           
        var $content = $container.find(".content-row");    
        var $alert = $container.find(".alert-open");        
        $container.css({
            "right": "-270px",
            "height": "40px",
            "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
        });
        $content.css({
            "transform":"scale(.5)",
            "transform-origin":"0 0",
            "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
        });

        state = "close";
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass("hide");            
        $($alert).removeClass("hide");
    });

    $(".alert-container").on("click", ".alert-popup .alert-open", function(e){            
        var state = "close" ;
        e.preventDefault();
        if (state === "open")
            return;
        var $container = $(e.target).closest(".alert-popup");           
        var $content = $container.find(".content-row");
        var $alert = $container.find(".alert-close");
        $container.css({
            "right": "0px",
            "height": "80px",
            "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
        });
        $content.css({
            "transform":"scale(1)",
            "transition": "all 1s ease 0s"
        });
        state = "open";
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass("hide");
        $($alert).removeClass("hide");
    });

    $(".alert-container").on("click", ".alert-popup .alert-kill", function(e){  
        var $container = $(e.target).closest(".alert-popup");
        $($container).css("display","none");            
    });
```

This is the final and fully functioning code. in case anyone finds themselves in a similar situation, maybe it will make it easier to get to the correct solution